# ForeignKey using ASP.NET MVC 4 Migration Code first

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, foreign-keys

How to create a foreign key into the below `User` class on the ID of the computer class?

User table:

```
[Table("User")]
class User{
 [Key]
 public int idUser;
 public int idComputer; //ForeignKey
}
```

Computer table:

```
[Table("Computer")]
class Computer{
 [Key]
 public int idComputer;
}
```

How to do a one-to-many relationship and one-to-one relationship between these classes, please?

Comment: This has nothing to do with MVC

Answer (score 4):

**To set it up so that a User has many Computers and a Computer has one User, you would do this:**

```
class User {
    public int idUser {get;set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Computer> Computers {get;set;}
}

class Computer {
    public int idComputer {get;set;}

    public int UserID {get;set;} // automatically detected as a ForeignKey since the format it [classname]ID
    public virtual User User {get;set;}
}
```

**To set it up so that a Computer has many Users and a User has one Computer, you would do:**

```
class User {
    public int idUser {get;set;}

    public int ComputerID {get;set;}
    public virtual Computer Computer {get;set;}
}

class Computer {
    public int idComputer {get;set;}

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users {get;set;}
}
```

**To set it up so that a User has one Computer:**

```
class User {
    public int ID {get;set;}

    public virtual Computer Computer {get;set;}
}

class Computer {
    public int ID {get;set;}

    [Required]
    public int UserID {get;set;}
    public virtual User User {get;set;}
}
```

The `[Required]` tag should eliminate any errors about the one-to-one relationship

As a side note, the whole point of EF Code First is to make things super simple and quick and easy, but when you don't use some of the features it offers it diminishes it greatly and you have to do more manual work, which can lead to mistakes.

[Here's a tutorial on how to do code-first. I recommend you read up on it.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/01/tutorial-series-updated-for-entity-framework-6-code-first-with-mvc-5.aspx)

Okay, I re-read your original question. You can't have both (one-to-one and one-to-many) between the same two classes, you can either have a one-to-one (i.e., a User has one computer and a computer has one user) or a one-to-many (i.e, a User has many computers and a computer has one user, or a computer has many users and a user has one computer.) It's a one or the other, not both, kind of thing. The fact that you think this is possible reinforces my statement that you **really need to read that tutorial** or read up on simple relational database structure

Comment: I'm currently running EF 6.0.2 version.

Comment: Okay, then all of what I mentioned above will work. Back to EF4 it should work, I'm not familiar with most things before that. But I highly recommend into having it map some of the stuff automatically. EF Code First is designed to do that, so why not use it?

Comment: Using what? but what about the `[ForeignKey("User")]`?

Comment: Using the auto-detection features of EF. With the way I specified it in the code above there's no need to say `[ForeignKey("User")]`, EF is smart enough to figure that out on its own.

Comment: Your solution isn't longer than EhsanSajjad's solution?

Comment: No they're both practically the same thing, I just specified why you should do it this way. When you use EF code first, there should be almost no time when you use data annotations to annotate a field with [ForeignKey] or [Key]. It makes one of the greatest features of Code First useless.

Comment: Your example works! Would you please provide a one-to-many example and a full working code of addition of row ?

Comment: But, why am I getting two foreignkeys into the Computer table?

Comment: I've updated my answer to show a one-to-many relationship. I suggest you read and actually study the link I provided as it will clear up many of the questions you have and will have about Code First.

Comment: Okay thank you, but, what about one-to-one relationship. My question was about these two kinds of relationships.

Comment: Sorry, but the second one isn't working (one-to-one).

Comment: The second one isn't one-to-one, it's one-to-many. Unless you mean the third, and by "not working", what exactly do you mean?

Comment: I'm getting this error while PowerShell migration `Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'Project1.Models.Computer' and 'Project1.Models.User'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.`

Comment: it's in, look at `Project1.Models.`

Comment: I updated my answer, accidentally mapped both c lasses instead of just the one class. Try that.

Comment: I'm still getting the same code error to the one-to-one relationship!

Answer (score 0):

this is one to one relationship:

```
[Table("User")]
class User{
 [Key]
 public int idUser {get;set;}
 public virtual Computer Computer {get;set;}
}


[Table("Computer")]
class Computer{
 [Key]
 public int idComputer {get;set;}
 [ForeignKey("idUser")]
 public virtual User user {get;set;}
}
```

for one-to-many, here relationship is one user has multiple computers:

```
[Table("User")]
    class User{
     [Key]
     public int idUser {get;set;}
     public ICollection<Computer> Computers {get;set;}
    }

[Table("Computer")]
    class Computer{
     [Key]
     public int idComputer {get;set;}
     [ForeignKey("idUser")]
     public virtual User user {get;set;}
    }
```

Example:

```
using(var db = new yourDbContext())
{

User user = new User();

user.Name = "Name";

db.User.Add(user);

db.SaveChanges();

Computer computer = new Computer();

// set properties here if any

Computer.CopmuterName ="Dell";

Computer.user = user;

db.Computer.Add(Computer);

db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: how to savechanges into the database? why adding the idUser and User instead of only idUser? what about idComputer and Computer instead of only idComputer ?

Comment: because with userid we also need row for user linked with it, EF automatically fetches user record as well related with the computer

Comment: but what about the `[ForeignKey("User")]`? Using your lines, will not more configurations?

Comment: now look at the edited version, it will clear you things

Comment: Why the data annotations? Instead of having EF detect it for itself, which it does if you specify things correctly, you're manually doing it?

Comment: it will do the required job, its quite easy to read and understand the relations in my approach

Comment: if some other person reads it he can easily judge the relationship due to annotations

Comment: Fair enough, in my experience it defeats the purpose of one of the coolest features of code first and adds more work to do. To each his own though.

Comment: yes you are right but it clears the thing to other person who sees your code first time

Comment: Would you please provide an example of use of these classes. For example, using `CDbContext _db = new CDbContext();`, CDbContext contains `Users` and `Computers` ?

Comment: An example like this.. `User u = new User(); u.computer = new Computer...`

Comment: please note that I'm getting this error while build time : `The modifier 'virtual' is not valid for this item`

Comment: Don't you need to insert into the ICollection?

Comment: that is for one to many case, i showed you example of one to one

Comment: you just need to add Computer and pass it User reference...if you defined in class one to many..

Comment: I still getting `The modifier 'virtual' is not valid for this item`. I'm quite sure that I've followed your example.

Comment: you are getting on what??

Comment: They need the `{ get; set; }` modifiers

Comment: yes @BenBlack is right get set is required for them